# Is there a possibility to decrease the clickable area of an item in HTML&CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to reduce the clickable area on website logo on my header. For example - lets suppose my website logo would be "A" in plain clickable text, and below that, a second row of text, which is also clickable. The result I get is that there is about 10% empty space on top and on the bottom of the letter, which is itself clickable. Addition to that, I want to add a second row of text right after the "A", and as I do so, the text below the letter "A" is placed 10% lower than it should be (with there being an empty gap between these two items).

***Just to clarify: I would like the clickable box on top of letter "A" to be exactly the width and height of the letter.***

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,600&display=swap"><!--CSS: font-family: "Lora", serif;-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test1.css">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="top-bar_content">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#" class="A_1">
            <p>
            A
            </p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="A_2">
            <p>
            Second Row
            </p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS specific for "logo" as follows:

```
/*.logo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}*/

.A_1 {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    /*padding: 5px 10px;*/
    /*margin: 0px;*/
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: "Lora", serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.A_2 {
    /*margin-top: -500;*/
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    font-family: "Lora", serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I have tried:

```
A_1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

***and setting a custom witdh and height to the letter "A" with no avail.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: managed to solve the problem myself. I fixed the letter's width and height by doing the following.

```css
.A {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 90px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 66px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```